# How to sort and display HTML files in a directory with their links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am creating a JQuery based blog. I'm using a static host. Being static it is very hard for me to display my latest posts somewhere ( say posts.HTML ) without actually editing posts.HTML .

I wanna show/list all HTML files stored in a directory named posts and their should be a posts.HTML which shows/lists the same ( if there is a this_is_a_new_post.HTML , it should list it This is a new post with its link)

Is there any way to do that in HmJQuery or JavaScript ? I know it is possible in php , but my host won't allowing me to use php.

So please help me to achieve that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should have a look on the '$.ajax()' or on the '$.getJSON()' methods and load your data from a Json file.

Read the doc': http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/